# Use php 'mt_rand' function in C#

Tags: c#, php

I'm trying to decode a token that was encoded in php, and one of the operations used to encode the token was the 'mt_random' function, so I ran into a problem to find the equivalent of mt_random in C #.
I realized that this function uses the “Mersenne Twisted Random Number Generator”, and I found in the C # class “MersenneTwister” from “MathNet.Numerics.Random”, which I thought would help me.
Code in PHP:

```
mt_srand(10);
$value = mt_rand(0, 8);
```

Code in C#:

```
var random = new MersenneTwister(10);
var value = random.Next(0, 8);
```

But, as I see, they have different results. I think this is due to the fact that they have another implementation of this algorithm.
Thus, there may be some library that can generate the same numbers as PHP.

Comment: How did you check for differences in the results? What was your sample size?

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky here, but these are random number generators. Why do you think they would generate the same sequence of numbers?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? According to the `mt_srand()` documentation, in PHP versions below 7.1.0 it used an incorrect algorithm.

Comment: I fixed this issue by implementing a linear congruential generator algorithm in both languages.

Comment: @asherber two rng istance generate the same sequence if seeded the same way. So C# mersenne twister and PHP mersenne twister should definly generate the same sequence, if the rng implementation is the same and the seed is the same

Comment: @Skary You’re right—I overlooked the explicit  seed.